# ID attribute in Weka

Tags: java, weka

I have a set of files and each file contains a unique identifier. I use Weka programatically and I create a training arff file. Each instance in the arff file corresponds to a set of attributes that I have extracted from each file, so one instance per file. How can I link the identifier of each file with the corresponding instance in the arff file. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the question completely - have you tried just adding a new feature that holds the identifier?

Comment: Can you please add code snippets for more clarity ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can associate an identifier with each instance by creating an extra attribute, [as described here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Instance+ID).

Thus, in your case, you would create a string attribute and add this attribute to each instance. When training and testing your classifier, you will want to remove the identifier, which can easily be done using either the [Remove Type Filter](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/RemoveType.html), which by default removes String types; the Remove Filter would also work, where you specify the attribute index.

If you are running Weka with the command line, you can use the -p option to output the predictions and attributes (even for attributes that are filtered);  see the bottom of the first link.

Answer (score 1):

If I do not misunderstand, you want to link 2, or more, arff files together.

Let's assume that we have two arff files which are named as `file1.arff` and `file2.aff`.

You can use the following code via the command line:

```
java weka.core.Instances append file1.arff file2.arff
```

Cheers